# AngularJS UI-Router: from main page to sub page - menu active

Tags: angularjs

I use AngularJS ui-router in my application and I have a mainPage where I can navigate to a subPage over clicking an icon at the main page.

If I am at subpage than main menu item is marked as active - this works fine.
But If I click at the main menu to get back to the main page where I came from than the menu item is deactivated (the active color is disappeared)
Here is my menu list item:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': vm.state.includes('auth.subPageReachedByIconOnPage')}" ui-sref="auth.mainPage" ui-sref-active="active"><a>Main Page Menu Text</a></li>
```

Is there any possibility to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-class` and `ui-sref-active` attributes override each other. For example, if your current state is `'auth.subPageReachedByIconOnPage'` `ng-class` will add `active` class to your `li` tag. If your state is `'auth.mainPage'`, `ui-sref-active` will add `active` class to your tag, but `ng-class` will override this changes and remove this class, because statement `vm.state.includes('auth.subPageReachedByIconOnPage')` returns false.

I see at least two ways to solve this issue:

1) Combine your statements for adding `active` class into one statement. To achieve this you should remove your `ui-sref-active` attribute and add additional statement to your `ng-class`. Something like this:

```
<li ng-class="{'active': vm.state.includes('auth.subPageReachedByIconOnPage') || vm.state.includes('auth.mainPage')}" ui-sref="auth.mainPage"><a>Main Page Menu Text</a></li>
```

**Example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TwJlF2r5ka9jTc5kKEXc).**

2) The second way is refactoring of your states in the app. You can move your `'subPageReachedByIconOnPage'` under `'auth.mainPage'` state. After that you can remove your `ng-class` attribute at all. Because `ui-sref-active` will add class `active` if user is on `auth.mainPage` or `auth.mainPage.subPageReachedByIconOnPage`. But I don't know anything about your application, so it can be not so easy to implement in your case.